# How to write text after a csquote-blockquote?

Tags: csquotes

Consider this MWE

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\renewcommand\mkblockquote[4]{\leavevmode\llap{\textooquote}#1#2\textcoquote#4#3‌}

\begin{document}
Text starts here.
\blockquote{A long quote. A long quote.
A long quote. A long quote. A long quote.
A long quote. A long quote. A long quote.
A long quote. A long quote. A long quote.
A long quote. A long quote. A long quote.
A long quote. A long quote. A long quote.
A long quote. A long quote.}%
(Text that should go directly after the quote. But only for this one quote!)\\
Text continues normally from here.
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to write further text (as shown in the parentheses) *directly after* the quote, in the same line after the quotation marks. But this is an exception and should only be made for this *one* quote.

Comment: What mean exactly "go directly after the quote"? In the same line ? In a new line but without a vertical space? With the same indentation?

Comment: same line, just after the quotation marks. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\renewcommand\mkbegdispquote[2]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\textquotedblleft\,}}
\renewcommand\mkenddispquote[2]{\,\textquotedblright#2}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1] 

\begin{displayquote}[Text after the quote]
\lipsum*[2]
\end{displayquote}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```